# Mosquitto on Raspberry pi stuck in local mode

Tags: raspberry-pi, mosquitto

I am attempting to get my Mqtt server to work on my network. Currently I receive the following message

Starting in local mode only. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.

Based on information from Mosquitto, I need to update the /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf file to allow for non-local access:

```
pid_file /run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location mosquitto/data
#/var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

But running with this adapted .conf file it does not allow non-local access. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the [man page of Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html), you can see, that listener specifies the port and bind address/host of the mqtt broker:

```
listener port [bind address/host/unix socket path]
```

Since version 2.0, the default config will only bind to `localhost`.
If you run version ^2.0, you only allow for local connections because no host is set. Therefore just change the listener line to:

```
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
```

This will allow any machine to connect, you can also specify explicit ip-addresses that are allowed to connect.

Comment: I added the 0.0.0.0 to the listener, but unfortunately no change, still the same message that I can only start in local mode. Is there some flag or such that I need to set?

Comment: are you running only ```mosquitto``` as command? If you start it from terminal, you have to specify your config file, e.g. ```mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf```. It might be needed to run as sudo there.

Comment: When I run with mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf, the following shows: Error: Duplicate pid_file value in configuration. I wonder if my whole setup is corrupt, perhaps I need to rebuild everything?

Comment: as mentioned, try ```sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf```, if this does not work, reboot your pi, and try again, or start it as service with ```sudo systemctl start mosquitto.service``` and then have a look at ```sudo systemctl status mosquitto.service```

Comment: Thanks, ran as suggested. I get the message ***Active: failed (Result: exit-code)***  Also ***Failed to start Mosquito MQTT Broker*** Also the message ***mosquitto.service: Start request repeated too quickly.***

Comment: Something about your installation seems to be off. You can uninstall mosquitto with ```sudo apt-get purge --remove mosquitto*``` and then reinstall it according to [this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/how-to-install-mosquitto-broker-on-raspberry-pi/). It worked for me out of the box. If it does not, you can check the logs of the systemd service with ```sudo cat /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250233/discussion-between-spanching-and-pete).